# DynamicObject? How does the following code work?

Tags: c#

I just can't seem to piece the following code together in the source code of MVC Webgrid.

When we are constructing the grid column, we do say

```
grid.Column("Id", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id)),
```

"item" is a lambda parameter obviously and it's actually a "WebGridRow" class.  (I THINK!! UNLESS I'm WRONG) See source code here

https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Helpers/WebGrid/WebGridRow.cs

My issue here is, "Id" is not a property of this class and since WebGridRow inherits from DynamicObject, how exactly the ".Id" property mapped to the "source object" of the current row?

Btw, the source object "object value" is passed through the constructor of WebGridRow

```
public WebGridRow(WebGrid webGrid, object value, int rowIndex)
{
    _grid = webGrid;
    _value = value;
    _rowIndex = rowIndex;
    _dynamic = value as IDynamicMetaObjectProvider;
}
```

Column definition

```
public Func<dynamic, object> Format { get; set; }
```

Column is invoked in "WeBGridRenderer" class as

```
 foreach (var row in webGrid.Rows)
 {
                     .....
                    foreach (var column in columns)
                    {
                        var value = ...Format(column.Format, row).ToString();
                        ...
                    }
 }
```

Finally, the "Format" function in "WeBGridRenderer"

```
private static HelperResult Format(Func<dynamic, object> format, dynamic arg) {
        var result = format(arg);
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Edit]**
I've written a fairly extensive blog-post on the subject over here: http://blog.alxandr.me/2013/07/26/dynamic-dispatch-how-dynamic-work-in-c/
If you are interested in how dynamic dispatch in C# works, this might explain quite a bit.
**[/Edit]**

I've worked a lot with the DLR, and it's a huge and complicated beast, but I'll try to keep this simple.

What happens when you do anything with a `dynamic` in C# is that the compiler generates a dynamic call-site. If you decompile the code you'd end up with something like `CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>` in most cases (not functions, they tend to have more than 2 parameters). The call-site does a lot of magic that we don't need to get too much into, but when an object implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` the dynamic callsite (or the binder used rather) invokes `GetMetaObject` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider.getmetaobject.aspx) on said object.

A `DynamicMetaObject`'s role is to describe how to perform dynamic operations against a given object. In your case, the dynamic operation is "read property named Id", so the callsite calls `BindGetMember` on the dynamic meta object. This `BindGetMember` can do anything it likes, however, in the case of `DynamicObject` it calls `TryGetMember` on the `DynamicObject` itself.

Now, there's a lot of caching (and black magic) involved, that makes this efficient, and `DynamicObject` provides a simple way to implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` (which can be a real beast to get right at times), but that still doesn't mean that every `dynamic` object is a `DynamicObject`.

For instance, if I do this:

```
dynamic test = "test";
int length = test.Length;
```

`test` (which is obviously a string) has no method `TryGetMember`. However the `CSharpGetMemberBinder` knows how to use reflection to figure out that `string` has a property named `Length` and return that.

Comment: Holy moly @Alxandr! Thanks for helping me out two times in a row!! I was too tired last night after trying to piece the puzzle together. What a great blog post! I might have to read couple of times to get fully "get it". but thank you and @Jon both for explain this piece to me. If I can, i would vote your answers as the best answer for me this year!

Comment: Getting a "server not found" for your blog. For future: https://web.archive.org/web/20130829054751/http://blog.alxandr.me/2013/07/26/dynamic-dispatch-how-dynamic-work-in-c/

Answer (score 3):

When you try to access a property on a `DynamicObect`, the [DLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx) calls its [`TryGetMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember.aspx) method at runtime (see [how WebGridRow implements it](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Helpers/WebGrid/WebGridRow.cs#L108)). What you get back is that method's result, provided through its `out` parameter.

A most important detail here is that your lambda function argument `item` is not typed as `WebGridRow` -- in that case this code would not compile. Dynamism is achieved because the signature of [`WebGrid.Column`](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Helpers/WebGrid/WebGrid.cs#L499) declares the `format` parameter as a `Func<dynamic, object>` -- it's the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) type of the argument that allows the DLR to take over.

Comment: Ah ha!! Thank you so much @Jon!! I'm not at all familiar with DynamicObject, learned something today again! Many many thanks!

Comment: @Liming: `DynamicObject` by itself is not capable of doing this -- the important part is that `item` is typed as `dynamic`. I added some clarification.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this is somewhat wrong. In the case of `DynamicObject` it is true, but that's because of how `DynamicObject` implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`.

Comment: @Alxandr: How could the answer be improved?

Comment: @Jon I tried to briefly explain how the call goes through the chain. Also, I started writing a blog-post that explains how the dynamic dispatch really happens. But as for your answer, simply state that this is only true for `DynamicObject`'s and not `dynamic` in general.

Comment: @Alxandr: IMHO that approach to answering this specific question is a little bit over the top (the OP has likely not encountered `dynamic` before), but +1 because it's worth it.

Comment: @Jon yeah, but the point is that a `dynamic` does not have `TryGetMember` (as you state), which makes your statement technically wrong.

Comment: @Alxandr: Indeed, that was poorly put yet I somehow didn't notice. Thanks for the feedback, fixed.

Comment: Thank you @Jon for taking the item to explain it to me. Learned a lot in this post from both you and Alxandr than I have done all year it feels. I wish i can mark both your answers as "answers"!!! Thumbs up!!!