# razor template delegate, how the inside works?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm reading this excellent article regarding razor template delegate. http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/9/simplifying_html_generation_using_razor_templates

While I understand how it's used, as in

```
Func<dynamic, HelperResult> variable = @<var>@item.ProductName</var>
```

My question is, how exactly razor engine translated "`@<var>@item.ProductName</var>`" into a delegate in the background? As in

```
Func<dynamic, HelperResult> variable = delegate(dynamic x)
{
   (what goes on in here?)
}
```

is `@item` a reserved keyword that razor parses out? Can it be used in any other convention? say `@column` or `@row` or any other ways?

Thanks a lot. Like I said, i'm more interested in how razor view engine translated the template statements into actual code in the background.

[Edit]. Thanks to Brad for pointing out Andrew's article. so above statement "`@<var>@item</var>`" will translate into

```
Func<dynamic, HelperResult> variable = delegate(dynamic item)
{
     return new Microsoft.WebPages.Helpers.HelperResult(__writer => {
     @__writer.Write(" ");
     @__writer.Write("<var>");
     @__writer.Write(item.ProductName);     <--- what's happening here?
     @__writer.Write("</var>");
}
```

So I see razor automatically parses out `@<var>` and `</var>` into separate strings and such, my question in regards to "item.ProductName" is..suppose "item" is a "Proudct" type, then is the following what razor is trying to do?

First, razor parses  "@item.ProductName" separated by comma ".", get "item" and "ProductName".

Then because of the "dynamic" parameter, in the background, .NET will attempt to find the value of the property "ProductName" of the item "Product"?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, `@item` is reserved and is a specific implementation. If you need something more robust/elaborate, you'll have to look in to a `@helper` or `HtmlHelper` extension. (further Reading: [Phil Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx), [Andrew Nurse](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2010/8/2/inside-razor-part-3-templates.html/), [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx))

Comment: Thanks @Brad. That explains part of my confusion. Do you know how razor view engine actually translated the statement into an anonymous delegate in the background? Much appreciate it.

Comment: I update the comment, check out those links (specifically Andrew Nurse's)

Comment: Thanks @Brad once again. Andrew sure explained where the item comes from. I'm editing my question, to be a bit more specific instead of asking a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I don't know why i didn't make the connection.

I asked another question in regards to DynamicObject [DynamicObject? How does the following code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875671/dynamicobject-how-does-the-following-code-work) and @Alxandr explained this regarding "dynamic". So essentially, it becomes

```
dynamic item = new Product(...);
String ProductName = item.ProductName;
```

So in essence, "dynamic" parameter in the background use CSharpGetMemberBinder and through reflection, figure out the "ProductName" of the object "Product".

razor template has a pretty brilliant design